# Docker cannot find GIT_TOKEN from .env file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, .env

Currently on MacOS Ventura 13.4.1

Docker & docker-compose versions:

```
Docker 24.0.2
Docker Compose version v2.18.1
Docker Desktop Version 4.20.1 (110738)
```

When I attempt to build my containers (either by `docker build .`, `docker-compose build`, `docker-compose up --build -d`) I get the same error:

```
 > [app stage-0  7/11] RUN --mount=type=secret,id=GIT_TOKEN     git clone "https://$(cat /run/secrets/GIT_TOKEN)@github.com/<gitrepo>":                                                        
#0 0.111 cat: can't open '/run/secrets/GIT_TOKEN': No such file or directory
#0 0.114 Cloning into '<name>'...
#0 0.256 fatal: could not read Password for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c git clone \"https://$(cat /run/secrets/GIT_TOKEN)@github.com/<gitrepo>"" did not complete successfully: exit code: 128
```

Dockerfile:

```
#pin to specific version
FROM node:current-alpine3.18

EXPOSE 8080:8080

WORKDIR /app

RUN apk update
RUN apk add git
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat

RUN --mount=type=secret,id=GIT_TOKEN \
    git clone "https://$(cat /run/secrets/GIT_TOKEN)@github.com/<gitrepo>"

WORKDIR /app/nfl-fad-next
COPY .env .

# pin npm/node to specific versions
RUN npm install -g pnpm
RUN npm install -g @types/react

RUN pnpm install

CMD pnpm dev
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15.2-bullseye
    environment:
      - PGDATA=/pgdata
      - POSTGRES_DB=fad
#      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=nfl
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/pgdata
    expose:
      - 5432
    ports:
      - 54325:5432
    secrets:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: image:0.1
    ports: 
      - 8080:8080
    env_file:
      - .env
    secrets:
      - GIT_TOKEN
secrets:
  GIT_TOKEN:
    environment: "GIT_TOKEN"
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD:
    environment: "POSTGRES_PASSWORD"
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

I have changed the path in my `.zshrc` file to `$HOME/.docker/bin`

I can confirm that my `.env` file is in the root folder and when I `echo $GIT_TOKEN`, the terminal returns the correct token.